# Como limitar la precarga de direcotrios de JFileChooser

Tags: java, excel, jfilechooser, sas

Tengo un programa en Java que busca y carga archivos Excel para utilizarlos en un proyecto SAS. Normalmente funciona bien, pero si trato de ejecutarlo en un servidor demora mucho tiempo. Al abrir el display del JFileChooser pasa de tardar 5 seg en un PC normal a 15 mins en un servidor.

Creo que es debido a que `JFileChooser` trata de hacer una precarga de los directorios de todos los discos y en este caso el servidor cuenta con muchos discos. Me gustaría saber si puedo limitar esta precarga o limitar la función de `JFileChooser` al disco actual. El programa hace lo siguiente:

```
private String createProyect() {
   JFileChooser fileopen = new JFileChooser();
   FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(NEW_PROYECT, EXTENSION_XLS, EXTENSION_XLSX);
   fileopen.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
   ...}
```

También había pensado en un archivo de configuración adjunto al programa pero no se como lo podría hacer.
Gracias por su tiempo. Saludos

Comment: Hello, we are in Stackoverflow in Spanish please edit your question by translating it so it can be accepted and answered, also to prevent it from being closed ;)

Comment: Hecho, gracias por el detalle.